# Do women in all-women shops earn less then men in all-men shops?

Tags: economics, gender, sociology, discrimination

Many women & men raise issues of equal pay for equal work, but a recent analysis of Uber Drivers showed that women earned less because of working less or driving slowly; Uber Payment system did not Discriminate between genders.

Similarly, those who say there is no Discrimination argue that women tend to work in companies with shorter commute probably with less pay, while men tend to work at companies where pay is more even if the commute is more. Also women take break in career. Etc, Etc, Etc.

Some relevant Posts like [Do women earn less than men for the same exact work?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/42364/do-women-earn-less-than-men-for-the-same-exact-work) & [Is the gender pay gap evidence of discrimination?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5159/is-the-gender-pay-gap-evidence-of-discrimination) & [Are women underpaid relative to men?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/908/are-women-underpaid-relative-to-men) have some supporting views or other opposing views, but a common concern is that all statistical studies compare apples to oranges because **It is not easy to statistically account for all variables** like age, education, experience, working hours, commute time, team composition, productivity, Etc, Etc, Etc.

Now the highlighted part is : **It is not easy to statistically account for all variables**

**In this scenario, is there any study which compares all-women shops to all-men shops ? It would compare apples to apples.**

Hypothetical case : Compare women in Baskin Robbins shop A which is run only by women versus men in Baskin Robbins shop B which is run only by men : If the profits of a shop are normalized, do men earn more ?

Shop A : $100 in profits per day, 6 women earn $10 each, total earnings = $60. Normalized earning ratio = 0.6
Shop B : $150 in profits per day, 5 men earn $15 each, total earnings = $75. Normalized earnings ratio = 0.5

Here men may earn more than women, but that is still less in term of generating profits.

I made up these numbers; Baskin Robbins is an example; It could be Pizza Hut or Used Car Dealers or Computer Service Centers or Banks or Laundromats or similar shops, where all the outlets are part of a big company with central owners.

**In cases like this, Is there Discrimination, with women earning less than men ?**

Comment: Can you clarify where the notable claim is here? This looks like a general question or a hypothetical scenario.

Comment: @DeNovo , I have given a hypothetical scenario to explain what sort of study I am looking for and what was the outcome of those studies; It is a general question just like the 3 questions I have linked in the Post. (None of the linked Posts have any notable claim)

Comment: @DeNovo , my Question is best summarized in the title. All other text is simply context , or Examples of what such a study to answer the Question may look like.

Comment: Voting to close.  There is no notable claim here, and this question has been addressed in other places on this site.

Comment: @DenisS , May I know where my specific Point ( summarized in the question title ) has been answered or addressed ?

Comment: @Prem Questions here must have a "notable claim", which is a claim that is widely believed. Please read [this](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2506/37236) for more information.

Comment: @Laurel & others, thanks for patiently commenting here, but I do not see any notable claims in the 3 linked questions, which have been upvoted 150 times in total, and have been answered as well... In my question, I only raise a similar specific concern which will actually resolve all the other questions...

Comment: @Laurel , Putting it in other words : My question is about Pay Discrimination, which is a notable claim and already asked and already answered as "we can not know" , .... but my variation is about Pay Discrimination in a specific case of "all-women versus all-men", which, if answered (or rather studied), would answer that Definitively.

Comment: @Prem Two of those questions are from 2011, when the site had just started, before the "notable claim" rule was created, although one of those questions does actually link to a notable claim (it can be tricky to fix old Qs to meet the new standards). The other question is closed as a duplicate, but if it weren't closed for that reason it would likely have been closed for not having a notable claim. I suggest you look for evidence that other people are making this claim and then edit it into the question.

Comment: If the question is about equal pay, it's not usually considered entirely (mainly?) an issue of outright discrimination. Many people are also fighting job segregation due to social attitudes, differential childcare expectations, and lack of support for reintegration after pregnancy.